# Converting non projected x,y coordinate into a specific projection in a 2D array

Tags: python, raster, scikit-image

I created a 2D array and after applying Gaussian filter I find centroid of all the connected pixels with values equal to 1 and then
save it with the projection EPSG:3413.

Using `skimage.measure.label`, I determine all the connected pixels and label them. After labeling, I calculate their properties such as area and centroid using `skimage.measure.regionprops()`. 
I am able to extract the centroid coordinates of the connected pixels but these coordinates do not have any projection associated with it at this step.

**Additional information:**

How to add/associate projection to the 2D array, so that other attributes such as coordinates are in projection (EPSG:3413) and can be used for future analysis?

I know I can save the 2D array with projection (EPSG:3413) and then open and re-read the 2D array again and calculate coordinates which would have the projection. However I want to avoid this step of saving and then re-reading the 2D array as it would add more time to the computation.

Comment: Are the coordinates from the beginning actually in EPSG:3413 or are you just labeling/defining them as using that CRS? If they're not 3413, you'll have to georeference or transform the coordinates to a known CRS using control points.

Comment: Hi @mkennedy, the 2D array does not have any CRS associated with it, so I will need to define EPSG:3413.

Comment: You can assign EPSG:3413 only if the coordinate values are correct for that CRS. Ex. I can't assign EPSG:4326 (WGS 84, latitude-longitude, degrees) to values like 100000, 200000. If you can build the matrix in lat-lon instead, assign a GeoCRS, then project to 3413.

Comment: Okay, so how do I build a 2D array with specific projection?

Comment: Can you edit your question (not as a comment) and explain more about what your desired end result is.  If you want to georeference an array to create a raster, you do not need the coordinates of each pixel.